# how to ensure a method runs only after all properties have been injected using @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Config class and need to define some beans inside this class, like:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mydb")
public class MyConfig {
    private String user;
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        ... some logic that needs the variables "user" and "password"
    }
}
```

and my property file `application.yml` looks like:

```
mydb:
  user: me
  password: pass
```

My question is, how do I make sure the variables `user` and `password` will be available when my bean `MyBean` is created?
I tried to use `@PostConstruct` for the method, but it doesn't work. I would like to hear about all kinds of solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `@ConfigurationProperties` class as it's own class, separate from other functionalities, and inject it where it's needed.

```
@Data // getters and setters
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mydb")
public class MyDbProperties {
    private String user;
    private String password;
}


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyDbProperties.class)
public class MyConfig {
    @Autowired
    private MyDbProperties myDbProperties;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        ... some logic that needs the variables "user" and "password"
    }
}
```

This is generally a good pattern to follow since Spring Framework is developed in a similar way. Example:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.html